# Is there a way to 'reset' USB connections without Restarting winXP?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, iphone

I am having trouble making connections to USB devices, Memory sticks, iPhones etc..

Is there anyway to clear what the operating system has assigned to the USB ports and have them all reconnect without restarting the system?

Sometimes plugging the device into a different port will not solve the problem.

using Windows XP

Answer (score 2):

In `Device Manager` (found in the Control Panel), under the `Universal Serial Bus controllers` section, disable and enable the USB Controllers that are listed.

Comment: Note that if you're using a USB Keyboard and/or mouse, they will effectively be disconnected from the computer. This will make it impossible to re-enabled the USB controller without a reboot. If you are using a PS2 keyboard/mouse, you shouldn't have to worry.

Comment: Note: Do *not* do this on a remote computer that is connected via USB WiFi. I feel so dumb right now.